# How to authenticate linux users against two different directories simultaneously?

Tags: linux, active-directory, openldap, freeipa

I have a few Linux servers using SSSD integrated with Microsoft AD to authenticate AD users.

AD groups are managed by a different department and I'd like to set up another directory to manage my own groups, but I can't just get out of the domain.

So, I'm thinking about installing a new OpenLDAP or IPA server to create my own groups, and to come up with a config in my Linux servers, so they would pull identities/groups from AD and from my LDAP at the same time. So if a user exists in both, the group list that the user belongs to, would be a superset comprised of both group lists.

e.g. - Let's say I have a user John that exists in AD and he is included in AD groups: "group1" and "group2". I would create the user (same uid) in my own directory and include him in "group3". So when the user login to my Linux server, he would be in "group1", "group2", and "group3".

How would that be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted on: http://serverfault.com/questions/824768/how-to-authenticate-linux-users-against-two-different-directories-simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

User information retrieval is actually separate from authentication – it's handled by nsswitch, not PAM.

Either way – the first thing to try would be configuring two domains in sssd (one AD, one LDAP) and seeing if sssd merges the lookup results from both.

If that does not work, set up nslcd or another alternative LDAP client while keeping sssd for AD, and list *both* modules in the system's `nsswitch.conf`. Results from different modules are usually merged (e.g. /etc/group can augment AD users).

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense and it's definitely worth to give it a try. I only have one question, if sssd doesn't handle user information whatsoever, how is that going to work if I added the two domains in sssd.conf? In that case that shouldn't make any difference. Thanks again!

Comment: @EloyAcosta: I never said it doesn't.